# Installing xvidcap Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, compiling, gtk

I downloaded **xvidcap** from [SOURCE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xvidcap/), and I'm supposed to follow following instructions:

```
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

But, after doing ./configure itself I get error:

```
checking for PACKAGE... configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.4.0 libglade-2.0 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-2.0' found No package 'libglade-2.0' found No package 'glib-2.0' found No package 'gthread-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGE_CFLAGS and PACKAGE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Which I don't understand. I have followed these links, but it doesn't help:

1. [Linux Questions: No package 'gtk+-2.0' found](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/no-package-'gtk-2-0'-found-695324/)
2. [Ubuntu Forums: Compiling xvidcap](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-828610.html)

But, they don't help. I still get the same error. Please help.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install gtk2.0`

Comment: @MarkKirby `uim-gtk2.0 is already the newest version (1:1.8.6-15)`

Comment: Is this installed too `libgtk2.0-dev`?

Comment: @MarkKirby Yes `libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.30-1ubuntu1).`

Comment: Why did you download source when a .deb is available? Any reason you need to build source when it is already packaged?

Comment: @MarkKirby I'm new to Ubuntu, I was told that with deb all dependencies are not met. If you are suggesting deb, can you please share a link to download it

Comment: You gave the link with the deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/xvidcap/ hang on and I will see what happens when installing.

Comment: That software was never updated for 16.04, do you need that software specifically? This does the same thing `sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop` and is still updated, try it out

Comment: @MarkKirby I wanted xvidcap as I'm acquainted with it. For now, I followed `sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop`. Is this only a commandline utility, can't I adjust the area of screen to be records or output type.

Comment: It has a UI that shows a pic of your desktop, draw a rectangle on that to highlight bit of desktop, next to this is a button `advanced` this lets you adjust settings, see this screenshot http://imgur.com/a/AAVDA That deb of xvid did work, however it is missing GTK2 modules and AFAIK I have them installed, it needs to be updated by the devs, you can try it though `gnome-software` will auto resolve any dependencies.

Comment: @MarkKirby Could you please answer for XVID as well as recordMyDesktop with steps that you followed. FYI: My Ubuntu is 64bit and debs are i386.

Comment: Just download the deb and double click it, it will open in gnome-software, 32bit can run on 64bit, that is all I did.

Comment: @MarkKirby I did `sudo dpkg -i xvidcap_1.1.7rc1_i386.deb` and got `Errors were encountered while processing:
 xvidcap:i386`